# 'Method not found: 'Void Module.train()'.'

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I am currently walking through the text classification instructions using Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharp-notebooks/blob/main/machine-learning/E2E-Text-Classification-API-with-Yelp-Dataset.ipynb

I'm just playing around with this library and wanted to train it to determine if based on a note string whether or not it would be rejected or approved. Currently I have a small console app that follows the instructions from the above link but I keep getting an error after calling Fit on the training set

This line:
`(_trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainTestSplit.TrainSet);).`

I know this is a very new feature, but I was wondering if anyone else has ran into this issue

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp;
using TorchSharp;

namespace ConsoleApp5 {
    internal class TextNLPClassifier {
        MLContext _mlContext;
        PredictionEngine<ExpenseNote, IssuePrediction> _predEngine;
        ITransformer _trainedModel;
        IDataView _trainingDataView;
        public void FitData() {
            // Initialize MLContext
            _mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);

            // Load your data
            //var reviews = RawData.GetData();

            var reviews = new List<ExpenseNote>
            {
                new ExpenseNote() { Note = "test", Sentiment = "Approved"}
            };

            var reviewsDV = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<ExpenseNote>(reviews);



            //Define your training pipeline
            var pipeline = ProcessData();

            BuildAndTrainModel(reviewsDV, pipeline);

            foreach(var rev in reviews) {
                var review = rev;
                review.Sentiment = "";
                var prediction = _predEngine.Predict(review);
                Console.WriteLine(prediction.Sentiment);
            }

            // Train the model
            var model = pipeline.Fit(reviewsDV);
        }

        IEstimator<ITransformer> ProcessData() {
            var pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "Sentiment", outputColumnName: "Label")
                .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName: "Note", outputColumnName: "NoteFeaturized"))
                .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "NoteFeaturized"))
                .AppendCacheCheckpoint(_mlContext);
            return pipeline;
        }
        void BuildAndTrainModel(IDataView trainingDataView, IEstimator<ITransformer> pipeline) {
            
            var trainTestSplit = _mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(trainingDataView, testFraction:0.2);
            
            var trainingPipeline = pipeline.Append(_mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.TextClassification(numberOfClasses: 2, sentence1ColumnName: "Note"))
                .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
            _trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainTestSplit.TrainSet);
            _predEngine = _mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ExpenseNote, IssuePrediction>(_trainedModel);
        }
    }
    public class ExpenseNote {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public string Note { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(1)]
        public string Sentiment { get; set; }
    }

    public class IssuePrediction {
        [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
        public string Sentiment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out for anyone in the future messing with this issue: I had to make sure all my packages matched these versions

```
<PackageReference Include="libtorch-cpu-linux-x64" Version="1.11.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Analysis" Version="0.20.0-preview.22313.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML" Version="2.0.0-preview.22313.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp" Version="0.20.0-preview.22313.1" />
<PackageReference Include="TorchSharp-cpu" Version="0.96.3" />
```